# XPages - xe:namePicker - select server name?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-extlib

Is it possible to select a server name for an xe:namePicker control? I would like to select an Address Book from a different server (not the one my application resides on).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a different server with

```
addressBookDb="ServerName!!names.nsf"
```

before the database name devided by "!!"

```
<xe:namePicker id="namePicker1">
    <xe:this.dataProvider>
        <xe:dominoNABNamePicker addressBookDb="ServerName!!names.nsf">
        </xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
    </xe:this.dataProvider>
</xe:namePicker>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for! I was in the process of implementing Naveen's solution above but this is much easier and quicker :-)

Comment: Oh my! [This isn't the first time `!!` has bitten me](http://naveegator.blogspot.in/2012/01/double-exclamation-bang-in-lotus-notes.html) :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`xe:beanNamePicker`](http://www.openntf.org/xspext/xpages%20extension%20library%20documentation.nsf/xpages-doc/xe_beanNamePicker.html) to do that. One example is the XSnippet - [Sample about NamePicker Data Provider (dataBean)](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=sample-about-namepicker-data-provider-databean).

There you can get handle of database (`names.nsf`) on different server and fetch its entries.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it would be nice if anyone else could suggest an easier solution though :-)

Comment: Thanks again, but I will use the solution below from Knut as it is quicker.